# C++ "map is not a type" error

Tags: c++

This is my header file:

```
/**
 * Job.h
 *
 **/

#ifndef JOB_
#define JOB_

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

class Job {

private:

int resourceId;
int inputRepresentation;
int outputRepresentation;

//Effects associative array
//Maps an effect to a map of it's attributes
//effectsMap[effect][attribute]=value
map< std::string, map<std::string, int> > *effectsMap;

public:

//constructors
Job();
Job(int resId, int inputRep, int outputRep);

//destructor
virtual ~Job();


//getters
int getInputRepresentation() const;
int getOutputRepresentation() const;
int getResourceId() const;


//setters
void setInputRepresentation(int inputRepresentation);
void setOutputRepresentation(int outputRepresentation);
void setResourceId(int resourceId);
void setRepresentations(std::map *rep);

void addEffect(std::string effect, map<std::string, int> attributesMap);



};


#endif
```

Now Ii will get to the point:

```
void setRepresentations(std::map *rep)
```

Gives the following error: "map is not a type"
This is weird because it looks like eclipse manages to properly link to the stl library...
And I do have a private field of map that seems to be fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the full type of the map, including the types inside the `< >`: Something like:

```
void setRepresentations(std::map<std::string, int> *rep);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `std::` in front of the map.

Answer (score 3):

`std:map` is a *template*, not a *type*. A type would be `std::map<std::string, int>`.

What exactly is `setRepresentations` supposed to do? Why does the signature not fully specify what type of `map` it should be working with, just like `addEffect` does?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the namespace for map, so it should be `std::map`.